# 2 Chronicles 36:9 Is it 8 or 18? And why?

Tags: hebrew, translation-philosophy

In 2 Chronicles 36:9 the Bible records to beginning of the reign of Jehoiachin over Judah.  Some Bible translations, KJV and NASB (1977 and 1995) among them, have translated the Hebrew word שְׁמֹנֶה (šᵊmōnê) as "eight" while others, NIV, NASB (2020), and Holman among others, have translated the same Hebrew word as "eighteen".  Why?

**2 Chronicles 36:9**

> **NIV** ~ 9 Jehoiachin was eighteen[a] years old when he became king, and he reigned in Jerusalem three months and ten days. He did evil in the eyes of the Lord.

> **KJV** ~ 9 Jehoiachin was eight years old when he began to reign, and he reigned three months and ten days in Jerusalem: and he did that which was evil in the sight of the Lord.

> **NASB** ~ 9 Jehoiachin was [a]eighteen years old when he became king, and he reigned for three months and ten days in Jerusalem. He did evil in the sight of the Lord.

> **NASB1995** Jehoiachin was eight years old when he became king, and he reigned three months and ten days in Jerusalem, and he did evil in the sight of the Lord.

Answer (score 1):

2 Kings 24:8
King James Bible

> Jehoiachin was **eighteen** years old when he began to reign, and he reigned in Jerusalem three months. And his mother's name was Nehushta, the daughter of Elnathan of Jerusalem.

Pulpit Commentary

> Jehoiachin was eighteen years old when he began to reign. In 2 Chronicles 36:9 he is said to have been only eight years old, but this is probably an accidental corruption, the yod, which is the Hebrew sign for ten, easily slipping out. As he had "wives" (ver. 15) and "seed" (Jeremiah 22:28), he could not well be less than eighteen.

Comment: Of 22 instances found of 'eighteen' being translated, none use yod to achieve 18. All use shm(u)nh-eight and oshr/h-ten.  There are so many variations between Kings and Chronicles (in more than dates) that I'm beginning to wonder if it is intentional rather than error. Many of the 'creative solutions' to anomalies don't quite fit. Just found this article...maybe Chronicles was dropped in from a parallel universe? :)  https://biologos.org/articles/the-books-of-chronicles-and-the-problem-with-literalism/

Comment: This is interesting. Perhaps you can post a specific hermeneutic question on this.

Comment: Would have to see if there are more authors who think like the article above. Also, it makes me want to do a side-by-side comparison of all the differences between Chronicles and related OT books. So many Biblical projects...so little time. :-(

Answer (score 0):

1. Chabad gives it as 8 Years. I trust this translation as closest to the Hebrew text.
2. Most of the translations could be from LXX & MT
3. Interestingly few versions print Eight[een] - Does this mean they are not sure?
4. Always good to pick a JPS version as you can be more confident of the translation of Tanakh.

https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/2%20Chronicles%2036:9

Answer (score 0):

Note the foot note to 2 Chron 36:9 -

> One Hebrew manuscript, some LXX manuscripts, and Syriac (see also 2
> Kings 24:8); most Hebrew manuscripts eight

This raises an interesting parallel to 2 Kings 24:8 -

> Jehoiachin was eighteen years old when he became king, and he reigned
> in Jerusalem three months. His mother’s name was Nehushta daughter of
> Elnathan; she was from Jerusalem.

There is no debate about the text of this verse.  Further we notice V15

> Nebuchadnezzar carried away Jehoiachin to Babylon, as well as the
> king’s mother, **his wives**, his officials, and the leading men of
> the land. He took them into exile from Jerusalem to Babylon.

That is, the fact that the king had several wives confirms that he was more than 8 years old.

Therefore, it is likely that the MSS that say "eight years old" in 2 Chron 36:9 is clearly an error is some - not all MSS say this.